# React (Native) loading component error on children

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a written a loading component for my React Native App that shows a loading screen as long as the data is not retrieved. This looks something like this:

```
function LoadingChecker({ children, data }) {
  const notLoaded = data.filter((item) => !isLoaded(item));

  if (notLoaded.length > 0) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.infoView, styles.centered]}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="information-outline" color={Colors.grey} size={45} />
        <Text>Loading ...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    { children }
  );
}
```

```
  return (
    <LoadingChecker data={[information]}>
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
        <Text>information.name</Text>
      </View>
    </LoadingChecker>
  );
```

The problem is that I get an exception indicating that *information.name* is undefined.

It seems to me that even tough I conditionally render the Text View, React is still preparing or evaluting it and because my *information* is undefined it fails.
If I replace *information.name* with *information?.name* it works and I see the loading screen, followed by the information screen.

I'm I doing something wrong? Could I tell React not to evalute the children?

Comment: Do you need `data` in `LoadingChecker` for anything else than making sure your data is loaded?

Comment: No. This uses react-redux-firebase and there is a method that tells me if this is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not doing anything with `children` in `LoadingChecker`, I don't really see the point of having `LoadingChecker` encapsulate everything to be honest.

I would do something like this instead:

```
function Loading() {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.infoView, styles.centered]}>
      <MaterialCommunityIcons name="information-outline" color={Colors.grey} size={45} />
      <Text>Loading ...</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

```js
return !isLoaded(information) ? (
  <Loading />
) : (
  <View style={styles.mainView}>
    <Text>{information.name}</Text>
  </View>
)
```

Otherwise if you want to keep your current structure, I don't think you could do anything better than `information?.name` like you suggested youself.

Comment: Yes I could do this but I wanted to avoid the additional conditional here.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that even tough I conditionally render the Text View, React is still preparing or evaluting it and because my information is undefined it fails

No, you're wrong here. If you're conditionally rendering some children, React will not prepare (there's no concept like that in React though) them on its own. To prove this issue I created a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-moore-7u0lz?file=/src/App.js), where I conditionally rendering a child component that uses an updated state value. As long as the state is not updated the parent component, `LoadingChecker`, will not render its child component,  `<p>Loaded done. {data.message}</p>` not it shows any error for `{data.message}`  rather it'll show 'loading' text. So, I think here you've some different issues with the shape of the data you're fetching.

Comment: cool thank you. Do you think maybe React Native is behaving different on this?

Comment: No. I don't think so because the core tools are provided by the same library, React. I created an expo snack here for you imitating what I did in CodeSanbox, you can check it out: https://snack.expo.io/@mateensr/conditionally-render-child-component

Comment: thx again. Then I need to dig deeper in my code :-)

Comment: You can upvote my answer and comments if you found them useful.